# Unable to get product names based on condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have two model classes

```
public class GetProductNameRequest
{
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class GetProductNameResponse
{
    public List<string> ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

linq query:

```
public async Task<List<ProductSKU>> GetProductNames(GetProductNameRequest request)
{
    var res = DbSet.Include(t => t.Product).Where(t => t.EndDate >= request.ExpiryDate && t.IsActive == request.IsActive).GroupBy(x => x.Product);
    Contracts.Models.ProductNameResponse product = new Contracts.Models.ProductNameResponse();

    foreach (var item in res)
    {
        product.ProductName = item.Key.ProductName;
    }

}
```

So i'm unble get list of Product Names based on Id's plz let me know the solution.

productsku table:

```
SkuId   ProductId   Sku MRP CreatedOn   UpdatedOn   StartDate   EndDate IsActive    RowVersion
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? please tell us in detail

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What is `DbSet`? what is `ProductSKU`? Where is the method's `return` statement and why don't you return `ProductNameResponse`? Where does "based on Id's" come into play? What's the relationship between `ProductSKU` and `Product`?

Comment: productsku and product are table entities..dbset contain productsku and also included product.

Comment: I asked a lot more. Please [edit] your question to add the relevant info.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems in your code. Two most obvious reasons why you don't get anything in your `product` variable is that it is initialized inside the loop, and nothing gets added to it. The code should be something like

```
Contracts.Models.ProductNameResponse product = new  Contracts.Models.ProductNameResponse();

foreach (var item in res)
{
    product.ProductName.Add(item.Key.ProductName);
}
```

I also think your LINQ statement will still throw an error about one cursor not close while another one is open. Search for IQueryable vs IEnumerable issue. But you don't list that as a problem; so maybe in your data source it is fine.

Comment: Flex im looking list of product names based on request..? and add not showing what u mentioned above line.